# What is wrong with my binomial expansion?

Tags: complex-analysis

The binomial expansion of $$(\cos x+i\cdot\sin x)^n$$
$$=\cos^n⁡(x)+n\cdot \cos^{n-1}⁡(x)( i\cdot \sin⁡x)+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!} \cos^{n-2}⁡(x) (i\cdot \sin⁡x )^2+\cdots+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\cos^2⁡(x)\cdot(i\cdot\sin⁡x)^{n-2}+n\cdot \cos⁡(x)\cdot (i\cdot \sin⁡x )^{n-1}+(i\cdot\sin⁡x )^n $$
WLOG
lets substitute $1$ in place of $n$ 
$$(\cos x+i\cdot\sin x)^1$$
$$=\cos(x)+( i\cdot\sin ⁡x)+ 0 +\cdots+0+\cos⁡(x)+(i\cdot\sin ⁡x )\\
=2\cos(x)+2( i\cdot \sin ⁡x)\\
=2(\cos x+ i\cdot \sin ⁡x)$$

---

Here is the procedure write down the binomial expansion then substitute a number in place of $n$.
by doing this we'll always get an extra coefficient $2$ . Can anyone explain the root of this error? 
Thanks!

Comment: You have only $n+1$ terms in the sum, in the case $n = 1$, $(\cos x)^1\cdot (i\sin x)^0 + (\cos x)^0\cdot(i\sin x)^1$. You need to stop when the descending exponent reaches $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question illustrates an issue with the $\cdots$ notation; it's not necessarily clear how to interpret it for small $n$, when there are more terms explicitly written out in the general formula than you actually want. To be clearer, you might write the same formula using the more compact summation notation:

$$(\cos x+i\cdot \sin x)^n = \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} \cos^j x (i\sin x)^{n-j},$$

where $\binom{n}{j} = \frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}$, and then you can plug in $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\cos x+i\sin x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(\cos x)^{n-k}(i\sin x)^k=$$
$$=\binom{n}{0}(\cos x)^{n}(i\sin x)^0+\binom{n}{1}(\cos x)^{n-1}(i\sin x)^1+...+\binom{n}{n}(\cos x)^{0}(i\sin x)^n=$$
$$=(\cos x)^{n}+in(\cos x)^{n-1}\sin x+...+i^n(\sin x)^n$$